# Laravel JSON Resource error Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve it, first time I make a Vue component that is a custom datatable, the problem is that when I use the filters only generates the error in Chrome and Firefox browsers but not in Microsoft Edge.

Which I attach below the error, my function and the Resource that returns the collection.

Error Message

```
message: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded",…}
exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "C:\\sites\\absoluto\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse.php"
line: 75
message: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
trace: [{file: "C:\sites\absoluto\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\JsonResponse.php", line: 54,…},…]
```

Controller

```
public function betaList(Request $request){
    // dd('Encontro funcion');
    $sortField      = $request->input('sort_field');
    $sortOrder      = $request->input('sort_order', self::DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    //Paginacion
    $per_page       = ($request->has('per_page') ? $request->per_page : 10);//? self::PER_PAGE;

    $filter_user_id = $request->input('filter_user_id');

    //Search
    $searchInput    = $request->input('search');

    $filter = $request->input('filter');

    $filter_status = $request->input('filter_status_id');

    $begin  = $request->input('search_begin');
    $end    = $request->input('search_end');

    if ($sortField == 'last_activity_at') {
        $sortField = Activity::select('created_at')
            ->whereColumn('activities.opportunity_id', 'opportunities.id')
            ->latest()
            ->take(1);
    }

    //Open query
    if ($filter_status == '5') {
        $query = Opportunity::closed();
    }elseif($filter_status == '6'){
        $query = Opportunity::closedFail();
    }
    else {
        $query = Opportunity::opened();
    }

    $query = $query->accessFilter()->newSearch($filter,$filter_status,$filter_user_id,$searchInput,$begin,$end);
    
    $documents = $query->orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)->paginate((int)$per_page);
    
    return OpportunitiesWithFiles::collection($documents);
}
```

JSON Resource

```
class OpportunitiesWithFiles extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'sales_man'     => ($this->user_id != null ? $this->user->name : null),
            'type_activity' => ($this->last_activity ? ActivityType::find($this->last_activity->activity_type_id)->name : null),
            'has_file'      => File::where('opportunity_id',$this->id)->exists(),
            'name'          => $this->name,
            'account_name'  => ( $this->account_id != null ? $this->account->name : null),
            'contact_name'  => ( $this->contact_id != null ? $this->contact->firstname : null),
            'status'        => $this->sales_stage->name,
            'sales_stage_id'=> $this->sales_stage_id,
            'type_close'    => $this->successful_closure,
            'line_product'  => ($this->lead_source_id != null ? $this->lead_source->name : null),
            'amount'        => number_format($this->amount, 0, ',', '.'),
            'created_at'    => ( $this->created_at ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->created_at)) : ''),
            'close_date'    => ( $this->close_date ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->close_date)) : ''),
            'probability'   => $this->probability,
            'activity_desc' => ( $this->last_activity ? $this->last_activity->shortDescription() : ''),
            'last_activity' => ( $this->last_activity ? $this->last_activity->created_at->diffForHumans() : 'Sin actividad'),
            'id'            => $this->id,
        ];
    }
}
```